# Counting rows in a sqlite db

Tags: linux, performance, sqlite

I have a sqlite db on an ARM embedded platform running Linux with somewhat limited resources. Storage device is a microSD card. Sqlite version is 3.7.7.1. The application accessing sqlite is written in C++.

I want to know the number of rows in several tables in regular intervals. I currently use

```
select count(*) from TABLENAME;
```

to get this information. I'm having trouble with the performance: When the table sizes reach a certain point (~200K lines), I have a lot of system and iowait load every time I check the table sizes.

When I wrote this, I though looking up the number of rows in a table would be fast as it is probably stored somewhere. But now I'm suspecting that sqlite actually looks through all rows and when I pass the point where the data doesn't fit into the disk cache anymore I get a lot of io load. This would roughly fit from db size and available memory.

Can anyone tell me if sqlite behaves in the way I suspect?

Is there any way to get the number of table rows without producing this amount of load?

**EDIT**: plaes has asked about the table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE %s (timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, offset INTEGER, value NUMERIC);
```

Comment: Probably this isn't terribly efficient, but you may modify your DB by adding triggers that increment/decrement a global row counter for each table. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html.

Comment: What happens if you add autoincrementing integer index?

Comment: @plaes: I looked at various query plans. It appears that the count query wants to look at all rows (0|0|0|SCAN TABLE channel_17 (~232666 rows)). When I create a test table with autoincrement rowid, this is still true. Sqlite Doku says: "[...] PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by creating an index in the database", so lacking an index should not be the problem.

Comment: Could you do the same 'analytics' with following table: `CREATE TABLE %s (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timestamp INTEGER, offset INTEGER, value NUMERIC);`? (When inserting insert NULL to `id` column)

Comment: @plaes: I did this for `CREATE TABLE %s (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timestamp INTEGER UNIQUE, offset INTEGER, value NUMERIC);`, this shows the same problem as before.

Comment: Hmkay, I'm all out of ideas. You could try raising that issue in sqlite mailinglists too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all the information I gathered, count() apparently really needs to scan the table. As plaes has pointed out, this is faster if the count is done on a integer indexed column, but scanning the index is still needed.

What I do now is store the row count somewhere and increment / decrement it manually in the same transactions I use to do inserts and deletes to keep it consistent.

Comment: How did you increase the counter, using triggers, or manually?

Comment: @hochl: I increase them manually. I don't feel I have enough experience with sqlite/triggers to do this safely enough in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Does this table have `integer` index? If not, then add one. Otherwise it has to scan the whole table to count the items.

This is an excerpt of comments from SQLite code that implements `COUNT()` parsing and execution:

```
    /* If isSimpleCount() returns a pointer to a Table structure, then
    ** the SQL statement is of the form:
    **
    **   SELECT count(*) FROM <tbl>
    **
    ** where the Table structure returned represents table <tbl>.
    **
    ** This statement is so common that it is optimized specially. The
    ** OP_Count instruction is executed either on the intkey table that
    ** contains the data for table <tbl> or on one of its indexes. It
    ** is better to execute the op on an index, as indexes are almost
    ** always spread across less pages than their corresponding tables.
    */
    [...]
    /* Search for the index that has the least amount of columns. If
    ** there is such an index, and it has less columns than the table
    ** does, then we can assume that it consumes less space on disk and
    ** will therefore be cheaper to scan to determine the query result.
    ** In this case set iRoot to the root page number of the index b-tree
    ** and pKeyInfo to the KeyInfo structure required to navigate the
    ** index.
    **
    ** (2011-04-15) Do not do a full scan of an unordered index.
```

Also, you can [get more information](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/eqp.html) about your query with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possible table row count workarounds (with caveats) that do not cause a table / index scan:

1. Note for tables where you can use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT as a primary key, you can grab the count from the sqlite_sequence sqlite meta-table:

   select name,seq from sqlite_sequence

seq will contain either the last id or the next id (I think the last but not sure).

2. "select max(pkid) from table", which will probably do an index search instead of a scan (and will also only be accurate for tables with no deletions).

Knowing this, if your use case includes UNIQUE deletions for tables you can use AUTOINCREMENT on, you could do a hybrid of the trigger-based solution and only count deleted rows (which would arguably be less bookkeeping than counting the inserts for most scenarios). However if you insert and delete the same row twice this also won't work.